# What is the difference between assignment of object with property, or assigning to property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, edit

I was learning to edit an array with a function and came across these two similar functions. I was wondering what is the difference between them. They both worked the same for me, but are there more pros or cons to using one of them?

```
function edit(position, newTodoText){
    userTodos[position] = ({todoText: newTodoText});            
    console.log(userTodos);
}
```

and

```
function edit(position, newTodoText){            
    userTodos[position].todoText = newTodoText;
    console.log(userTodos);
}
```

Comment: One is `thing = {key: value}` the other is `thing,key = value`.  The former overwrites the previous value of `thing`.  The latter requires that `thing` is already an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that the second option requires `userTodos[position]` object to already exists and would cause an exception if it doesn't.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'todoText' of undefined
```

Another difference is that the second option performs mutation (which means it edits an existing todo) while the first option creates a new todo at the same position (and the old one is deleted via something called garbage collection)

Here's some code with commentary to illustrate the differences:

```js
function optionOneInserts(x) {
  x[0] = { name: "alice" };
}

function optionTwoMutates(x) {
  x[0].name = "alice";
}

let x1 = [{ name: "bob" }];
let x2 = [{ name: "bob" }];

let previousFirstItemInX1 = x1[0];
let previousFirstItemInX2 = x2[0];

console.log("Current first item in x1 and x2:");
console.log(`current x1[0] = ${JSON.stringify(previousFirstItemInX1)}`);
console.log(`current x2[0] = ${JSON.stringify(previousFirstItemInX2)}`);

console.log(`\n...performing options one and two`);
optionOneInserts(x1);
optionTwoMutates(x2);

console.log("\nboth options end up with same values in x1 and x2:");
console.log(`x1 = ${JSON.stringify(x1)}`); // [{ name: 'alice' }]
console.log(`x2 = ${JSON.stringify(x2)}`); // [{ name: 'alice' }]

console.log(
  "\nbut the first option leaves its old first value untact and adds a new value, while the second option changes the old value instead:"
);

console.log(`previous current x1[0] = ${JSON.stringify(previousFirstItemInX1)}`);
console.log(`previous current x2[0] = ${JSON.stringify(previousFirstItemInX2)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first form will create *a new object* at the given position with *only one property* while the second form will *extend an already existing object* at that position with the given property and contents.

For the second form to be a bit more "tolerant" you could modify it to

```js
function edit(position, newTodoText){            
        (userTodos[position]=userTodos[position]||{}).todoText = newTodoText;
        console.log(userTodos);
}

const userTodos=[{done:"object created"},{todoText:"nothing"}];

edit(3,"something else");
edit(2,"and also this");
edit(0,"fill it up!");
```

`(userTodos[position]=userTodos[position]||{})` will create a new object at the given position if it does not yet exist, otherwise it will continue to work with  (=extend) the already existing object.